# Mocking a function that modifies an input argument in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest, python-mock

I have the following file, `main.py`:

```
def modify_in_place(obj):
  obj['foo'] = 'bar'

def foo(obj):
  modify_in_place(obj)
```

I also have a test for this:

```
import main
import unittest
from mock import patch

def side_effect(s):
  s.update(foo='bar')

class MainTest(unittest.TestCase):
  @patch('main.modify_in_place', side_effect=side_effect):
  def test_foo(self):
    state = {}
    main.modify_in_place(state)

    m_fn.assert_called_once_with({})
    self.assertEqual(state, {'foo': 'bar'})
```

This, however, returns the following error:

```
AssertionError: Expected call: fn({})
Actual call: fn({'foo': 'bar'})
```

The argument `state` is being modified in-place by `modify_in_place`, and the side effect in the mock does the same thing. When it's originally added to the call stack, the state variable is empty. When it's modified by the side effect, though, it has the (unintentional) side effect of modifying the object on the call stack. As a result, the assertion fails.

I locally modified [this line](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/unittest/mock.py#L961) to be

```
import copy
_call = _Call(copy.deepcopy((args, kwargs)), two=True)
```

When I did, the test passed.

Any ideas on how I can solve this without modifying the `mock` library?

Comment: This code does not can be executed. Try to fix it.