# How to check call arguments in mock for function that modifies its argument, such as random.shuffle?

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, alias

(This is related to the as-of-yet unanswered question [Mocking a function that modifies an input argument in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51032853/mocking-a-function-that-modifies-an-input-argument-in-python).)

I use Python's `unittest.mock` to mock `random.shuffle`, which takes a list object as argument and shuffles it in place.  As replacement functionality, I use

```py
def my_shuffle(lst):
    lst[0], lst[1] = lst[1], lst[0]  # swap first two items
```

as follows:

```py
from unittest import mock

with mock.patch('random.shuffle', wraps=my_shuffle) as shuffle_mock:
    lst = [0, 1]
    random.shuffle(lst)

print(shuffle_mock.call_args)
```

The output is

```
call([1, 0])
```

I expected `call([0, 1])`.

The issues seems to be that the mock captures call arguments by storing a reference, rather than a copy. This can be confirmed by printing `id`'s.

Consequently, the following assertion fails, which seems counter-intuitive:

```py
shuffle_mock.assert_called_once_with([0, 1])
```

Questions:

- How can I get the desired (and expected) behavior (with intuitive error reporting)?
- Is this a feature (what would be the motivation for that?), or a bug?
  Maybe it is an 'unfortunate necessity', because fixing it would require copying, but then you get into the problem of 'how deep'.

Of course, I could check for `call([1, 0])`, but that looks strange, especially in the error reporting.  (Note, that my code is part of a test frame for educational use; so error reports go to students, who should be helped, not confused.)